# How come abbreviations acquired the apostrophe when referring to plurality?

Tags: grammatical-number

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [What is the correct way to pluralize an acronym?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/503/what-is-the-correct-way-to-pluralize-an-acronym)
>   [What is the proper way to indicate possession when using an abbreviation such as Dr.?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10286/what-is-the-proper-way-to-indicate-possession-when-using-an-abbreviation-such-as)

An example:

> Most DD's have good packaging skills.

How did things come to that instead of:

> Most DDs have good packaging skills.

Compare that to:

> Most Debian Developers have good packaging skills.

[**update**] This question was asked with the presumption that the first example is correct, so I was surprised to find that it isn't the case.

Comment: They don't. Many style guides recommend no apostrophe in "DDs".

Comment: check this link. I think the question is duplicated.

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10286/what-is-the-proper-way-to-indicate-possession-when-using-an-abbreviation-such-as/10292#10292

Comment: @man Although it's related, it really is a different question (and answer).

Comment: The other question is about abbreviations like _Dr._, which is a very specific type of abbreviation.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: well then, how about this: [What is the correct way to pluralize an acronym?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/503/what-is-the-correct-way-to-pluralize-an-acronym)

Comment: @RegDwight: That is indeed the correct one.

Comment: It's not really a duplicate.  He isn't asking which usage *is* correct, he's asking how the incorrect usage arose.

Comment: @chaos: fair to say, but I don't think there's a reliable and objective answer to *that* question. Speculating that it's just too many people going "OMG here comes an S" at once is probably as objective as it gets. Which is to say: not objective at all. Also, note OP's edit; he wasn't even aware that this usage is not universally recommended, which is precisely what is addressed by that other question. Had he found it, he probably wouldn't be asking this one.

Comment: @RegDwight: Thankfully, this is SE, not Wikipedia, so I am allowed to answer based on truth, not verifiability. :)

Comment: @chaos: I didn't even notice that that answer was by you. (^_^)

Comment: @reg I still think this question shouldn't be closed. Also, I might as well tag this one [history]. I also don't  see why this can't objectively answered. Sure @chaos's aswer might be a mere guess, but it's a *very* good one, and a number of voters see to agree.

Comment: Duly noted, Tshepang. Note that we still need two close votes, so it won't be closed *necessarily*. Also, chaos' answer will stay for people to upvote and yourself to accept even if the question does get closed.

Comment: @chaos there was a real duplicate a month later at http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16967/why-did-they-spell-urls so the question can still be answered.

Answer (score 4):

The (IMO, mistaken) apostrophe-based usage arises out of a feeling of awkwardness in simply appending an *s* or *es* to an acronym or initialism.

Answer (score 1):

The first quote is still considered incorrect, although (depressingly) widely used.
"DDs" is likely to be strongly favoured (or favored for our US members) here...