# What is the Function of Apostrophes in this Idiom?

Tags: grammar, idioms, punctuation

The idiom *'Cross your Ts and dot your Is'* is often written with apostrophes as though they were in the possessive forms:

> Cross your T's and dot your I's

It's ubiquitous online, even on dictionary websites. But I don't understand why the apostrophes and don't know the rule of grammar that permits it. Can someone please explain the correct rule that governs writing it to me?

Comment: The (apparently) predominant style would have you use the apostrophe when pluralizing an individual letter of the alphabet.  (I prefer to cross my eyes.)

Comment: It's not a matter of grammar ("T's", "t's", "Ts", and "*t*s" all behave the same in terms of grammar), but of typographical style.  Both styles of writing the plural of letters (with an apostrophe and without) are considered acceptable in general.

Comment: Also related: [correctly dotting the “i”s and crossing the “t”s in the expression “dotting the i's and crossing the t's”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/212424/correctly-dotting-the-is-and-crossing-the-ts-in-the-expression-dotting-the)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's an evolving orthographic style.

The orthographic "rule" current when I was growing up in the 1950s was that the plurals of "non-words" (numbers, letters, initialisms) should be formed with *-'s*.

- For instance, what I have just written as *the 1950s* was supposed to be written as *the 1950's*.

That rule was still current when I was in graduate school in the 1970s; but a few writers and publishers were already pluralizing these forms with bare *-s*, and over the last forty or fifty years most publishers and styleguides have adopted that style. But there are still many who follow the old "rule".

Comment: A way of representing this visually so that the pluralizing *s* isn't thought of as "part" of the word is to put it in a lower font size than the word it modifies. This produces a similar effect to *DOs and DON'Ts* without having to resort to the use of capitals.