# What is the difference betwwen "the '80s" and "the 80's"?

Tags: punctuation

"The 80's" is a song made by Robbie Williams - Rudebox.

My question is what is the difference betwwen "the '80s" and "the 80's"? (what does it mean for the different positions of apostrophe?)

Comment: For as long as I can remember there have been opposing factions relative to the the use of "s" to pluralize items that are not conventional English words.  Numbers, individual letters, initialisms, etc.  It seems to me that the use of the apostrophe is dying out, but you still see it.  And if you were to go back in time and claim that using the apostrophe is *wrong* then many 1950's-era prescriptivist linguists would be Pist.  Besides which, song titles get a free pass -- they can use whatever they want.

Answer (score 4):

Strictly speaking, "the 80's" is wrong.  Apostrophes are used to denote possession or contraction (as JonHanna points out in the comments, apostrophes have other uses, but these are the only two that we need consider as possibly being relevant here).

The contraction here is from "1980s", so the correct form of the contracted version is **'80s**.  80s, without the apostrophe, can be seen as a less formal variant of this, but "80's" doesn't really make sense: the only time you would say "the 80's" is if "the 80" (singular) is a thing that can have possessions, and you're referring to one of them.

So, Robbie Williams' song title is grammatically incorrect.

Comment: I was reading [usage of same](http://www.k12reader.com/term/apostrophe/) and starting to think if Robbie Williams was right or wrong.

Comment: *O'Reilly* is neither a contraction nor a possession. *Qur’an* is neither a contraction nor a possession. *mus’haf* is neither a contaction nor a possession.

Comment: @JonHanna proper nouns don't really follow any rules of grammar, they just are what they are.

Comment: No, there is a consistent rule in English that Irish names like *Ó Raghallaigh* are written with an *O'*. Also *mus'haf* isn't a proper noun.

Comment: (Or strictly, *qur'an*; while we're almost always speaking of *the* Qur'an when we use the term in English it would remain valid to use it of any recitation).

Comment: @JonHanna the "rule" you refer to sounds like a "rule" (more of a convention, I'd say) for translating Gaelic proper names to English proper names.  I still think that isn't grammar per se.  I don't know what "mus'haf" is - is that an English word or phrase?  It looks Arabic. Is your point simply that as well as indicating possession or contraction, apostrophes have other uses, none of which happen to be relevant to this question?  If that is your entire point, I'm happy to edit my answer to indicate this.

Comment: Yes. Apostrophes have several uses, and have had more in the past. Another such use is with pluralising numbers; once considered the standard form though now rapidly dying out.

Comment: Oh, *mus'haf* is indeed an Arabic word, but it is the English spelling of it. The Arabic spelling مصحف has no apostrophe, since Arabic has no such mark, and nor do most transcriptions into other languages, the use of the apostrophe in such words is an English thing.

Comment: @JonHanna I've edited my question.

Comment: It still claims *"the 80's" is wrong*.

Answer (score 3):

*the 80's* is one of several examples of where apostrophes are or were used within plurals. Some of these are now completely dead in contemporary modern English (e.g. *waltz’s* was once acceptable because it was a loan word that ended in *z*, but that would not be acceptable today), and the rest are rather old-fashioned and increasingly not used. It's old-fashioned enough that I would recommend against it. See [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/104235/15770) for more.

*'80s* is making it clear that the *19* of *1980s* has been elided. Generally decade names (*80s*, *90s*, etc.) are easily-enough recognised without it, so this too is not as common as it used to be.

Since they are both forms found, albeit not so often as they once were, you might wonder why *'80's* is generally not found. As a rule even when apostrophes with plurals were more widely accepted than they are today, one would not use it with a term that already contained an apostrophe. So for example we had the spelling "do's and don'ts" where the first word used the apostrophe with a plural of a mention rather than a use of a word (yet again, not as often done today as in the past) while the last word does not use *'s* even though it is also a plural of a mention. Similarly, while *'80s* and *80's* are both still found today, and were more common in the past, *'80's* generally was not.