# How has using apostrophes in plurals caught on so?

Tags: greengrocers-apostrophe

I'm curious.  How has wrongly inserting an apostrophe to indicate a plural noun become so widespread?

I was born in the 60s.  Thirty years ago, in England at least, the only time you'd see it would be in greengrocers (Potato's 50p/lb - grrrr!).  Now, it's everywhere.  An extraordinary and increasing proportion of people seem to assume that it's required for almost every plural.

The thing is, it can't be laziness.  It requires more effort, not less, to type the extra character, when in the majority of cases, an 's' is all you need.

How did it start?  And how did it catch on?

Edit:

I should say, I've often suspected that it was originally a [hypercorrection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercorrection), like 'between you and I', also now widespread.

I suppose, that the more people see the construction, the more people that haven't either read widely (an increasing proportion of young people, I'd speculate) or been taught well, will assume it's correct and propagate it further.  I suspect social media of contributing substantially to this process.

I think what I'm really asking, is, does anyone know of any actual evidence to support or refute these hypotheses?

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apostrophe) dates the use of the apostrophe itself from 1496 ( Pietro Bembo in his edition of De Aetna) but is vague about the history of the usage of the 'Greengrocers' Apostrophe'.

Comment: It's often laziness. Mental laziness.

Comment: How can this type of thing be proven? It can't be, really.  Its occurrence can be observed.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it looks like a rant / invitation to discussion. But the relevant usage is also covered by [Why did they spell it “URL’s”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16967/why-did-they-spell-it-url-s?noredirect=1&lq=1) *(...the apostrophe should only be added to plural **s** if the word would otherwise become unreadable or exceedingly ambiguous.)*

Comment: @Lambie, good point of course.  It may be a question with no clear answer.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - It's not a rant at all.  The fact that misuse of apostrophes irritates me, which I don't deny, does not make my question a rant.   If such questions are so unwanted here (despite it being about the evolution of the language), perhaps I should post it on psychology.stackexchange.

Comment: @ChrisA: Google Books claims 153 published written instances of [***a 70's band***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22a+70%27s+band%22) - not so far behind the 218 hits for your preferred [***a 70s band.***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22a+70s+band%22) Personally, I've always tended to prefer the first version there (and I was getting a degree in English in the 70's! :)

Comment: (...and don't even get me started on *mind your **p's** and **q's**!* :)

Comment: But I'm with *the linguists Rodney Huddleston and Geoffrey K. Pullum* on your link re ***between you and I***, where they *claim that utterances such as "They invited Sandy and I" are "heard constantly in the conversation of people whose status as speakers of Standard English is clear" and that "Those who condemn it simply assume that the case of a pronoun in a coordination must be the same as when it stands alone. Actual usage is in conflict with this assumption.*

Comment: You only offer anecdotal rather than testable / vetted evidence that what you claim is true. I'd say that there are now just more signs rather than a vastly greater proportion of misplaced apostrophes. Though the fact that managers no longer tend to produce in-house signs probably lends some credibility to your claim.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: It should of course be "a 70s' band" ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think the fraction of the population which perpetrates greengrocers' apostrophes has not increased in size. Thirty years ago, material 'in print' tended to be either written by or edited by professionals, but these days anybody with access to a phone or computer can produce text.

Comment: Surely that should be *which perpetrates **greengrocers'** apostrophes* :)

Comment: There must be a name for that type of error... karmic?

Comment: I think it's the relatively unusual *plural* form that thows us. Google Books has 108 instances of [greengrocer's apostrophes](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22greengrocer%27s+apostrophes%22) against 333 for [greengrocers' apostrophes](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22greengrocers%27+apostrophes%22). The second feels much more "right" to me, if only because if there's going to be *one* "unusual" plural, there may as well be *two*.  Whereas *greengrocer's apostrophe* and *greengrocers' apostrophe* get 1650 and 1270 hits respectively (and are both "fine" by me! :)

Comment: Well, I think it should be "the greengrocer's apostrophe" or "greengrocers' apostrophes".

Comment: I absolutely agree! Both *singular+singular* and *plural+plural* are fine. I note that syntactic singular conveys semantic plural in, say, *He uses the greengrocer's apostrophe on all his signs*. Which may not the only reason anyway, but those Google Books hits suggest a singular preference, so to speak. For my part though, I just think it's interesting that of the other two permutations, I find *plural+singular* far more "questionable" than *singular+plural*.

Comment: Of course, it's always *We'll have two ploughman's lunches, please, barman* - never ***ploughmen's***, and only illiterates would misplace the apostrophe as ***ploughmans'***, or omit it entirely.