# Using possessive apostrophe s of a singular abbreviation that ends with s

Tags: grammatical-number, possessives, abbreviations, apostrophe

Which one is correct?

1- The OPS structure.

2- The OPSs structure.

3- The OPS's structure.

4- The OPS' structure.

OPS: A singular abbreviation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [Proper Apostrophe Usage with Initialisms: CCS' or CCS's?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/42922/proper-apostrophe-usage-with-initialisms-ccs-or-ccss) the conclusion was that the trailing *s* is dropped when the thing's singular name ends in an *s*. Correct usage would then be #4, *The OPS' structure*.

I think there is a little more to it than that; for example *my boss's house*. I think the best guide is whether you actually pronounce the possessive as *oh-pea-ess* or  *oh-pea-ess-iz*.

The [most popular related question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/79081/which-singular-names-ending-in-s-form-possessives-with-only-a-bare-apostrophe?rq=1) comes to the same conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

Strunk & White's "Elements of Style" recommends always use 's.

Comment: Hi, Stan. This answer was flagged as low-quality because of its length and content. Unless you expand your answer including why 's should be used with research/reference, this answer will be deleted by voting. Remember, we will delete all one-liners regardless of whether it answers the question or not. I don't think your post answers the question.

Comment: Sigh… I tried. -

Comment: Also ... Stunk & Wight ...